# How do I stop a Redirect Loop? Apache2 on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ssl, https, ubuntu-20.04

I have a DigitalOcean Ubuntu 20.04 Droplet. Connected to a Domain and SSL Cert from Namecheap. Everything works fine. I'm trying to add a redirect from http://example.com to https://www.example.com. HTTPS and WWW. When I try my domain. I get an error saying "too many redirects." I can't access the page. No Apache. So I'm in a Redirect loop. Between www and non-www. My /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf is:

```
`<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName example.com
      Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName example.com
      Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html
      SSLEngine on
      SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example_com.crt
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example_com.key
      SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/example_com.ca-bundle
 </VirtualHost>`
```

So, how can I stop the Redirect Loop? I also have /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:30

```
 `<VirtualHost *:443>
       ServerName example.com
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html
       SSLEngine on
       SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example_com.crt
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example_com.key
       SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/example_com.ca-bundle
  </VirtualHost>`
```

Does this look correct? Please take a look. And reply. With how I can stop the redirect. Loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust your Vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example_com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/example_com.key
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

To have the following result:

```
http://example.com -> https://www.example.com
http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com
https://example.com -> https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com -> Stays the same
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Can I add "https:// example.com" to "https:// www.example.com"? (Not stay the same?)

Comment: I tried the comment on 443 and it works. Restarted apache. Redirects fine. But can I add www to https? Like above comment? Thanks again

Comment: I have updated my answer with the not to www redirect for HTTPS Vhost 443.

Comment: I'm back. I will try Rewrite Rule and Condition. And report back. Thanks again

Comment: I'm back...Sorry I was busy. I tried your second reply and it won't connect. No apache screen. On the web. For my Domain. Should I enter EXACTLY what you posted? Should I replace anything like "%{HTTP_HOST}" with "example.com"? Should Comment the link for 443? Redirect 443? Like Before. And I can't restart/start Apache. With the new entries. Please reply. Anyone. Thanks

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay, I have adjusted my comment with my code update tested and it works as expected.